# ¿Como utilizar un solo formulario donde sus campos estan en diferentes tabs, jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

El diseño de pestañas en html queda de esta forma

```
<div class="tabs-animated-wrap">
    <div class="tabs">
        <div id="tab1-2" class="tab active">
            <div class="list login-form-box">
                <form id="formulario_creacion_multa1" class="form nice-label">
                    <div class="content-block-title">
                       <h2>Datos del vehiculo</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="idboleta"><span class="icon-document"></span></label>
                        <input type="text" id="idboleta" placeholder="Ingrese numero de boleta">
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="numplaca"><span class="icon-news"></span></label>
                        <input type="text" id="numplaca" placeholder="Ingrese placa">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2-2" class="tab">
            <form id="formulario_creacion_multa2" class="form nice-label">
                <div class="content-block-title">
                   <h2>Datos del Infractor</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="conducto"><span class="icon-user"></span></label>
                    <input type="text" id="conducto" placeholder="Nombre conductor">
                </div>
                 <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="conductor_ausente"><span class="icon-user-minus"></span></label>
                    <input type="text" id="conductor_ausente" placeholder="Conductor ausente">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

En estas pestañas tengo dos formularios `id="formulario_creacion_multa1"`y `id="formulario_creacion_multa2"`, pero en realidad debería ser únicamente un formulario ya que los campos de ese formulario los guardare en una tabla de la BD, de momento solo mostre algunos campos, pero en realidad son mas al igual que otra pestaña. Como podria hacer para tener solamente un formulario que este distribuido en los tabs y como aplicarlo en jquery.validate

De antemano muy agradecido.

Comment: Puedes escribir el <form> al principio y cerrarlo al final. Esto incluirá todos los campos para el validate

Comment: No entiendo el porque tenes dos `<form>` si debería ser un formulario, sólo tenes que tener uno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes colocar tu código así tranquilamente:

```js
let boton = document.getElementById("obtener");
boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  
  let form = document.getElementById("formulario_creacion_multa").elements;
  console.log(form)
  console.log(form[1].value)
});
```

```css
#obtener{
margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario_creacion_multa" class="form nice-label">
     <div class="tabs-animated-wrap">
        <div class="tabs">
            <div id="tab1-2" class="tab active">
                <div class="list login-form-box">
                    <div class="content-block-title">
                       <h2>Datos del vehiculo</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                       <label for="idboleta"><span class="icon-document"></span></label>
                       <input type="text" id="idboleta" placeholder="Ingrese numero de boleta" name="idboleta">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                       <label for="numplaca"><span class="icon-news"></span></label>
                       <input type="text" id="numplaca" placeholder="Ingrese placa" name="numplaca">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tab2-2" class="tab">
               <div class="content-block-title">
                  <h2>Datos del Infractor</h2>
               </div>
               <div class="form-row">
                  <label for="conducto"><span class="icon-user"></span></label>
                  <input type="text" id="conducto" placeholder="Nombre conductor" name="conducto">
               </div>
                  <div class="form-row">
                     <label for="conductor_ausente"><span class="icon-user-minus"></span></label>
                     <input type="text" id="conductor_ausente" placeholder="Conductor ausente" name="conductor_ausente">
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<button id="obtener">Obtener datos del formulario</button>
```

Si te fijas coloque e formulario como una etiqueta superior que engloba a todo, aparte a los campos le coloque el atributo **name** por si necesitas hacer un **serialize**, y coloque un **js** donde al darle el botón **Obtener datos del formulario** puedas ver los valores del formulario con sus elementos y verifiques que si esta leyendo todos los inputs asi esten en diferentes pestañas, si te fijas hay dos **console.log()**, el primero para que te fijes que elementos tiene el formulario y el segundo veas como obtiene el valor de uno de ellos. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Buena noche estimado, de esta forma puedo aplicar sin problemas jquery validate.

Comment: si, pero tendrías que detectar cual es el campo que esta dando el error en la validacion y activar el tab donde esta para que lo muestre, ejemplo si estas en la pestaña 1 y el campo que esta dando error esta en la pestaña 2 en tu js debes de indicar cuando los campos que esten en la pestaña 2 de un error muestras en tab 2 es decir le colocas la clase active a la pestaña de igual forma para la pestaña 1 si estas en la pestaña 2